# No Projects shown while trying to setup Debug configuration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have installed Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0). And also imported 2 Gradle Java projects.
When I try to debug it, so for that I need to provide Debug configuration as we do in Eclipse.

I clicked on Debug Configuration-> Remote Java Application -> New Configuration->Connect.
But while doing that, there are no projects shown when I click on Browse Button.

[image]

**How to solve this problem?**

Also , when I open any java file , it shows 'J' symbol as shown below. J's outlining is double.

[image]

Comment: The outline _J_ means the Java source file is not in a source file and will therefore not compiled. Eclipse provides several import operations. It seems you did not use _File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_ to import or something is wrong with your `build.gradle` files which are also missing in your question.

Comment: @howlger: I followed the same path: File>Import... Gradle > Existing Gradle Project

Comment: All that can be said based on the given information (cropped screenshot shows editor icon which is an outline _J_) is that the Java file is not in a source folder or is excluded. More information is needed to help (see my first comment).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the project was not able to build itself. And Build Path was not shown under Project Properties. So just go to Project > Properties > Project Facets and tick Java from there.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open Package explorer(the thing that shows all the files)?
If not go to
window--> show view --> Package explorer

Comment: maybe try leaving debug mode and shift-clicking the files you want, then go back?